# Using 'Present Perfect' with 'in the past'

Tags: present-tense, perfect-aspect

This came across when I was browsing an Australia gaming website, this is the whole sentence:

> "In the past, Hideo Kojima has been a regular at the PlayStation
>   Awards when his games have won."

So I'm wondering why they're using the Present Perfect with "in the past" in there, because from my understanding, Present Perfect is used when you say something that is still related to the present-days.

Therefore, I think that sentence should have been: *"In the past, Hideo Kojima **was** a regular at the PlayStation Awards when his games **had** won."* Is that corrent?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I agree. That's a grammatical error.

Comment: @William : Would you please be more specific about it? I'm assuming that my fixing would be more correct, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe any of *perfect*, *simple past* or *past perfect* might be used here.

If it were the *perfect* the implication might be that *in the past* meant the *recent* past.

But I also think that the two tenses need to match. i.e. one of the following is needed:

> 1.In the past, HK has been a regular...when his games have won.
>
> 2.In the past, HK was a regular...when his games won.
>
> 3.In the past HK had been a regular...when his games had won.